# Argument of type WCHAR is incomaptible with parameter of type const char*

Tags: c++

```
DWORD Snapshots::getWindow(const char* windowName)
{

    initVariables::hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0); 
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry; /// new variable named pEntry, that works around tagPROCESSENTRY32
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); /// compiler will deny any other value that doesn't fit in tagPROCESSEENTRY32  /// also using tagPROCESENTRY32
    do
    {
        if (!strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, windowName))  /// we compare the found exe to the exe's name we need.
        {

        }
        return 0;
    } while(Process32Next(initVariables::hSnapshot, &pEntry));  /// 1. arg = our handle 2. arg  = us referencing pEntry as our lpme


    return 0;
}
```

I am using multi-byte char set, this error only happens in DEBUG mode, in release it somehow doesn't.

Comment: What is the exact error message, and what line does it occur on?  We'll also need to see the variable definitions to get to a [mre].

Comment: WCHAR is a defined value which may change depending on the complier setting. This may explain why you don't get the same messages in debug vs release mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/wchar

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem you're asking about, but you're not calling `Process32First` before checking `pEntry.Entry.szExeFile`.

Comment: Check your project properties for debug configuration. Did you set multi-byte only for release build?

Comment: Error happens at line 9 ( !strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, windowName )

Comment: @jkb seems fixed now, never had to manually switch the configuration in property pages before, usually just did in toolbar, now it wasn't doing it automatically. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code won't compile when the project charset is set to Unicode (which is clearly the case) as `strcmp()` takes `char*` input, not `wchar_t*` input.

Since the code is using the `TCHAR` version of the Win32 API, it should use `_tcscmp()` to match:

```c
#include <tchar.h>

DWORD Snapshots::getWindow(const char* windowName)
{
    initVariables::hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (initVariables::hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry; /// new variable named pEntry, that works around tagPROCESSENTRY32
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); /// compiler will deny any other value that doesn't fit in tagPROCESSEENTRY32 /// also using tagPROCESENTRY32

    if (Process32First(initVariables::hSnapshot, &pEntry))
    {
        do
        {
            if (!_tcscmp(pEntry.szExeFile, windowName)) /// we compare the found exe to the exe's name we need.
            {

            }
        }
        while (Process32Next(initVariables::hSnapshot, &pEntry)); /// 1. arg = our handle 2. arg = us referencing pEntry as our lpme
    }

    CloseHandle(initVariables::hSnapshot);

    return 0;
}
```

However, since `windowName` is `char*` instead of `TCHAR*` and thus is not affected by the project charset, use the ANSI based API directly:

```c
#include <tchar.h>

DWORD Snapshots::getWindow(const char* windowName)
{
    initVariables::hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (initVariables::hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry; /// new variable named pEntry, that works around tagPROCESSENTRY32
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); /// compiler will deny any other value that doesn't fit in tagPROCESSEENTRY32 /// also using tagPROCESENTRY32

    if (Process32FirstA(initVariables::hSnapshot, &pEntry))
    {
        do
        {
            if (!strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, windowName)) /// we compare the found exe to the exe's name we need.
            {

            }
        }
        while (Process32NextA(initVariables::hSnapshot, &pEntry)); /// 1. arg = our handle 2. arg = us referencing pEntry as our lpme
    }

    CloseHandle(initVariables::hSnapshot);

    return 0;
}
```